# Comparing values of 2 columns from 2 tables and counting the total matches in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 tables in my rails application one of them is `Products` and the other is `Users`.

In the products table I have a `created_by_id` which is an integer that matches the id of the User who created it.  I need to display a running total of the Products and I am having an issue doing so.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def ensure_logged_in
    unless current_user
      flash[:alert] = "Please log in"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def totalprods
   Product.all.joins(:users).where("created_by_id LIKE current_user.id").count
  end

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

i'm new to rails so i am sorry if i am screwing something up

Comment: With properly set associations, you should be able to do `current_user.products.count` (or `current_user.created_products.count` or whatever the association name is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/models/user.rb` file, add:

```
has_many :products, foreign_key: 'created_by_id'
```

Then you can use:

```
current_user.products.count
```

PS: It's a good idea to call that column `user_id` instead of `created_by_id` since Rails can guess the association column if it's in the format `<model_lower_case>_id`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will re-create the value to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around 'current_user.id'.  Also, have you defined a relationship between your user and product models?

Answer (score 0):

Based off your question you could do it one of 2 ways 
The Long Way:

```
def totalProds
   count = 0
   @products = Product.all
   @products.each do |product|
      count = count + 1
   end
   return count
end
```

If your models are setup properly you should be able to use the short method which would be

```
def totalProds
   @products = Product.all
   count = @products.count
   return count
end
```

The second method would be the preferred unless you had to do something in conjunction with the count being added to your counter. Ruby offers a lot of small functions like this already.